# Data is not receiving in caller function after the fetch HTTP request

Tags: javascript

I have a `js` function fetch that needs to fetch some data and then I have other functions that relly on fetched information in order for them to work. As a result, my fetch takes too long so other functions give me an error that there is no "data" for functions to use. How can I make it so that before any of my functions start to work, first fetch gathers information?

```
console.log("Hello");

fetch("https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/113/senate/members.json",{
        method:"GET",
        headers:{
                 "Content-type": "application/json",
                 "X-API-Key": "eKDuyBWdpQGhsiKGi7geFoBmJR3kCRIRUGRWIASL" 
    }
})
    .then( (response)=>{
        if(response.ok){
            return response.json();
        }else{
            throw new Error('BAD HTTP stuff');
        }
    })
    .then( (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch( (err) =>{
        console.log('ERROR: ', err.message);
    });
```

The errors I get are

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"
>       at houAtt.js:1 and then the first line is: var members = data.results[0].members;

Comment: can you show us where you need to use `response` ?

Comment: Where is your other function which is giving error?. From your code I see you are not returning the `Promise` object.

Comment: It looks like you expect the result to be synchronous, whereas it is not. Other fonctions have to wait for the response before executing

Comment: your code doesn't even put the retrieved `data` anywhere - so `(data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }` is the only place it can ever be used

Answer (score 0):

When you rely on data which is retrieved using `AJAX`, you should wait to recieve the [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

So, let's say you API function is

```
function callAPI(){
    return fetch("https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/113/senate/members.json",{
            method:"GET",
            headers:{
                     "Content-type": "application/json",
                     "X-API-Key": "eKDuyBWdpQGhsiKGi7geFoBmJR3kCRIRUGRWIASL" 
        }
    });
}
```

This function will return the `HTTP` promise.

So, in the caller function you can catch the data.

```
function caller(){
  try {
    callAPI().then( (response)=>{
      if(response.ok){
        console.log(response.json());
      }else{
        throw new Error('BAD HTTP stuff');
      }
    });
   } catch(err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ', err.message);
   };  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(..)
.then(response)
.then((data)=>{
    //Your function code
});
```

Did you try synchronizing as like this? 
Also can you share more on how what you are fetching and how your functions are dependent on the response? That will help answer your query